# Prove that the ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ generated by $x^3-x^2+x-1$ and $x^4+3x^2+2$ is a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove that the ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ generated by $f(x)=x^3-x^2+x-1$ and $g(x)=x^4+3x^2+2$ is a prime ideal.

Also, prove that  the ideal generated by $r(x)=x^3-x^2-x+1$ and $s(x)=x^4+x^2-2$

Call the ideal generated by these two polynomials $P$. For $P$ to be prime we need that if $a(x)b(x) \in P$ then $a(x) \in P$ or $b(x) \in P$.

So i didn't make too much progress on this yet, hah, as of right now i'm trying to figure out a mistake I must have made in my algebra somewhere finding the roots of $g(x)$... So the roots of $g(x)$ are $(+/-)i,(+/-)\sqrt{2}$ but when i multiply the corresponding factors $(x-i)(x+i)(x+i\sqrt{2})(x-i\sqrt{2}$) I get $(x^2+1)(x^2+2)=x^4+4x^2+2$... so I don't know why the three keeps turning into a four.. Man i think i need a break.

Anyway if anyone can help me resolve the smaller problem which I have dug myself and the actual problem I asked that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You can note that $f(x)=x^2(x-1)+x-1=(x-1)(x^2+1)$ and $t^2+3t+2=(t+2)(t+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Over any field, the ideal generated by two polynomials is the ideal generated by their g.c.d. So use Euclidean algorithm to find the g.c.d. of these polynomials.

Comment: And when I find the $gcd$ what then? If the ideal is prime, will it the generator be an irreducible or osmething?

Comment: Yes, you'll find an irreducible  g.c.d.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since ${\Bbb R}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, the ideal generated by the polynomials $f,g$ is principal. This ideal has the monic generator $x^2+1$ which is irreducible in ${\Bbb R}[x]$.

Use polynomial division as below.

The ideal generated by $r,s$ is principal and has the monic generator $x^2-1$ which is reducible in ${\Bbb R}[x]$.

Polynomial division gives $r = (x+1)\cdot s + 3(x^2-1)$. So the ideal generated by $r,s$ contains $x^2-1$ which is the desired principal generator.

You can check the correctness by using Singular:

```
> ring r = 0, (x), lp;
> ideal i = x3-x2+x-1, x4+3x2+2;
> std(i);
_[1] x2+1
> ideal j = x3-x2-x+1, x4+x2-2;
> std(j);
_[1] = x2-1
```